# Give a div a Colored Background on hover + giving the colored background an opacity

Tags: css, hover

Currently i'm running into this problem.

I'm loading an img as background-image for the div: "first-portfolio-item".

Now when i hover over the image it changes it's opacity but what i would like is that the opacity of the color changes and that would appear on top of the image.

```
<div class="span4 first-portfolio-item">
    <a href="#" class="hidetext" alt="header">Header</a>
</div>

.first-portfolio-item{

    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    cursor: pointer;

    background-image: url('../img/header-image.jpg');

        &:hover{

            background-color: #3FF;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the CSS background-image you change the opacity of the background(image) as you are tring to change the opacity of the color background.
Try to use a `<image>`-Tag instead and use the `&:hover` on the containing div.

Answer (score 1):

You can not out the background-color over the background-Image. But you could add a Second background-image or use box-shadow for a nice Flow effect. For what i know, you don't Need the filter: ... Attribute animore.

Try to replace your CSS with this:

```
&:hover
{
    Box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgb(63, 243, 255,0.5);
}
```

If you want to fill your link with this color, just make the shaddow   bigger.

```
 &:hover
    {
        Box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px rgb(63, 243, 255,0.5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

provide position absolute and relative, see and giving below css properties try with hover on it..

```
.first-portfolio-item{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
   position:absolute;
   background-color:red;
}

a:hover{
        background-color:white; 
        opacity: 0.99;
        filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
        position:relative;
    }
```